# Android icon dosent change

Tags: android, web, webview, icons, mobile-website

Iam using Android Studio i tried using Image Asset,replaceing the image in the folder manually after all that i can see in Android Studio in the Android Mainfest

```
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"//i see the image on the side
```

the i con i created but when i launch the app on my phone i see the Android ic_launcher default icon.
i tried to go to Build > Rebuild project and after clean project and even File > invalidated Caches and still i got the Android default icon.
When i open the ic_launcher.png in any file in res i can see my own icon but on launch i see the default android icon.

Code:
Mainfest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

activity_main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">//ive tried this but it dosent work either

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: did u replace icon from all folders of drawable?

Comment: ive replaced instead of removing

Comment: check my updated comment

Comment: if you replace and not able to chnage icon then add icon with diffrent name and change it

Comment: yes i do (by the way in Android Studio its overwrite it when using Image Asset so... i also did it manually)

Comment: Clean-Rebuild-Restart

Comment: you should also consider switching to mipmap and discontinue using the drawables to avoid similar issues in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Try remove images from `res` folders.
2) Build and run the app.

If you notice any changes definitly its cache issue. also try delete `bin` folder and re-build the app.

Answer (score 0):

Once Reinstall your app.

and make sure to change your image in all drawable folders

```
drawable-hdpi<br>
drawable-mdpi<br>
drawable-xhdpi<br>
drawable-xxhdpi ... and others you have taken
```

It might be possible that you have changed ic_launcher from one of the drawable, but your device doesn't taking image from that folder.

Comment: ive changed all (by the way in Android Studio its overwrite it when using Image Asset so... i also did it manually)

Comment: change `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` to some other image and check whether its working or not, but make sure to reinstall your application

Comment: by reinstall you mean rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest versions the **mipmap folders** are used for placing app icons unlike putting in the drawable folder in earlier versions.

The following folders inside res folder could contain the app icons

```
res 
   -- mipmap-hdpi
   -- mipmap-mdpi
   -- mipmap-xhdpi
   -- mipmap-xxhdpi
```

you may want to switch to mipmap folders rather than continuing to use the old way. The mipmap folder is specifically meant to contain the app icons.